# AngularJS : Using factory inside a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

This is my first attempt to use the Angularjs and I'm trying to create a service and use it inside a controller:

```
var appTest = angular.module("appTest", ["ngRoute"]);
var appTestControllers = angular.module('appTestControllers', []);

appTest.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $routeProvider.
            when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl'
            });

            $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
    }
]);

appTest.factory("booksApi", function($http){

    var _getBooks = function() {
        return $http.get('http://localhost/editora-voo/website/books.json');
    };

    return{
        getBooks: _getBooks
    };

});


appTest.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http, booksApi) {

    booksApi.getBooks().success(function(data) {
        $scope.books = data;
    });
}]);
```

But it is returning an error: Cannot read property 'getBooks' of undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed to add `booksApi` depnedency inside your controller dependency array, You should add it first and then use that inside the function of controller.

**Controller**

```
appTest.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'booksApi', //<--missed dependency here
  function($scope, $http, booksApi) {
    booksApi.getBooks().then(function(response) {
        $scope.books = response.data;
    });
}]);
```

[**Plunkr Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/zCcO4vhWrDa9nof9ziwo?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But now appear this error: Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider

Comment: @marcelo2605 did you change your controller code as I suggested..? could you paste whole console error here

Comment: Yes. Here is the error: Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/$injector/unpr?p0=aProvider%20%3C-%20a%20%3C-%20booksApi

Comment: @marcelo2605 you should also remove `.` from `$routeProvider.
            when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl'
            }).` which is placed at the end

Comment: I remove the other conditions and forgot to remove ".". This is not the problem.

Comment: @marcelo2605 as per your updated question you missed to add dependency inside your controller `appTestControllers.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'booksApi',
  function($scope, $http, booksApi) {`

Comment: @marcelo2605 take a look at the plunkr and updated answer